# JavaFX ImageView memory leak

Tags: java, memory, javafx, memory-leaks

I work on image slide show application on JavaFX and after a while of working java crash with no free memory error.
In interface code I have:

```
image = new ImageView();
Group root = new Group(image);
imageScene = new Scene(root, height, width);        
primaryStage.setScene(imageScene);
```

In background thread I set image source for image view:

```
...
Map<String, Image> imagesMap = new HashMap<>();
...
// Slide thread
if (!imagesMap.containsKey(item.File)) {
Image image = new Image(item.File);
imagesMap.put(item.File, image);
}
Image i = imagesMap.get(item.File);
image.setImage(i);
```

While app run(with params:  -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx256m) memory allocated to java process always is increasing...

Comment: Have you profiled the application and confirmed that ImageViews are using all that memory?

Comment: Heap usage is around 20 mb, manual calls to GC from profiler doesn't showed memory reduction, app runs on Ubuntu box.

Comment: How many images does your map hold? If you keep calling the second code snippet with new images, the map will keep growing and prevent all those images from being garbage collected...

Comment: App contains 10 images, memory initial are used 59 mb after 1 hour around 100mb

Comment: In memory are 20 mb of objects, and bigger size are used by byte[], also in memory are no dead objects, without HashMap are same results - memory usage is always increasing

Comment: @Jhon. Comment out the sliding image codes you posted, and try to profile again. Maybe leakage is arising from different code snippet in your app.

Comment: At least I don't see memory leak in java's heap, heap is always around 20 mb but java process may take more than 100 mb after a while

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score -6):

Reduce the image size using the below code

```
Image img = ic.getImage();  
Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(500, 700,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

I am sure you are using the original image size in this app.

Comment: The question relates to `javafx.scene.image.Image`, not `java.awt.Image`.  There is no `getScaledInstance()` method on the JavaFX Image class.